# Can I override the title attributes on an H2 tag within a specific drupal region or block?

Tags: theming

I have a region within a site theme I'm working on, and would like the H2 title attribute to be white as opposed to the rest of the theme which calls for a blue. Can I use CSS to assign specific font size and color attributes to the title tag for that specific region/s within the theme?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to style the H2 tag inside a specific block.

Your block should have a unique ID, based on the name of the block.

Your CSS would look something like this:

```
<style>
#block-your-blockname h2 {
 color: white !important;
}
</style>
```

Note: you may not need "!important", and that CSS can go in your main CSS file if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed this, thank you very much for responding, it was of course the right solution!